# Move a File from Azure File Storage to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have rather foolishly uploaded a vhd to Azure file storage thinking I can create a virtual machine from it only to find out it really needs to be in blob storage.

I know I can just upload it again - but it is very large and my upload speed is very slow.

My question is - can I move a file from file storage to blob storage without downloading/uploading again? I.e. is there anything in the Azure portal UI to do it, or even a PowerShell command?

Comment: Do take a look at AzCopy. I'm not in front of a computer so I can't share exact details but it should be possible to copy a file from file storage to blob storage. However please keep in mind that the copied blob will be of type "BlockBlob" and not "PageBlob". If you want it as "PageBlob" then you would need to reupload it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy):

```
AzCopy.exe /Source:{*URL to source container*} /Dest:{*URL to dest container*} /SourceKey:{*key1*} /DestKey:{*key2*} /S
```

> When copying from File Storage to Blob Storage, the default blob type is block blob, user can specify option /BlobType:page to change the destination blob type.
>
> AzCopy by default copies data between two storage endpoints asynchronously. Therefore, the copy operation will run in the background using spare bandwidth capacity that has no SLA in terms of how fast a blob will be copied, and AzCopy will periodically check the copy status until the copying is completed or failed. The /SyncCopy option ensures that the copy operation will get consistent speed.

Answer (score 3):

In c#:

```
public static CloudFile GetFileReference(CloudFileDirectory parent, string path)
{
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
    var fullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    if (fullPath == string.Empty)
    {
        return parent.GetFileReference(filename);
    }
    var dirReference = GetDirectoryReference(parent, fullPath);
    return dirReference.GetFileReference(filename);
}

public static CloudFileDirectory GetDirectoryReference(CloudFileDirectory parent, string path)
{
    if (path.Contains(@"\"))
    {
        var paths = path.Split('\\');
        return GetDirectoryReference(parent.GetDirectoryReference(paths.First()), string.Join(@"\", paths.Skip(1)));
    }
    else
    {
        return parent.GetDirectoryReference(path);
    }
}
```

The code to copy:

```
// Source File Storage
string azureStorageAccountName = "shareName";
string azureStorageAccountKey = "XXXXX";
string name = "midrive";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(azureStorageAccountName, azureStorageAccountKey), true);
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference(name);
CloudFileDirectory directorio = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
CloudFile cloudFile = GetFileReference(directorio, "SourceFolder\\fileName.pdf");

// Destination Blob
string destAzureStorageAccountName = "xx";
string destAzureStorageAccountKey = "xxxx";
CloudStorageAccount destStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(destAzureStorageAccountName, destAzureStorageAccountKey), true);
CloudBlobClient destClient = destStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer destContainer = destClient.GetContainerReference("containerName");
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("fileName.pdf");

// copy
await TransferManager.CopyAsync(cloudFile, destBlob, true);
```

Comment: The answer is correct but the CopyAsync method has become obsolete as of today.
await TransferManager.CopyAsync(file, destinationBlob, CopyMethod.SyncCopy);

This should help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Azure CLI...

```
az storage copy -s /path/to/file.txt -d https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]
```

More info here: [az storage copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_copy)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gaurav Mantri for pointing me in the direction of AzCopy.

This does allow me to copy between file and blob storage using the command:

```
AzCopy.exe /Source:*URL to source container* /Dest:*URL to dest container* /SourceKey:*key1* /DestKey:*key2* /S
```

However as Gaurav also rightly points out in the comment the resulting blob will be of type Block Blob and this is no good for me.  I need one of type Page Blob in order to create a VM out of it using https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd

There is no way to change the blob type as far as I can see once it is up there in the cloud, so it looks like my only option is to wait for a lengthy upload again.

Comment: Actually you can copy file to page blob per http://aka.ms/azcopy: "When copying from File Storage to Blob Storage, the default blob type is block blob, user can specify option /BlobType:page to change the destination blob type."

Comment: Ah ha - that would have done perfectly!  I re-uploaded in the end and all is fine.  If you want to write your comment as an answer though - I think it is the correct one...

Comment: Posted my answer :)

Comment: "The syntax of the command is incorrect. Copying asynchronously from File Storage to Blob Storage as page blob is not supported." --AzCopy

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Data Factory or Synapse.

- Create a new pipeline
- Use the Copy activity
- Set up a Fileshare as the **source**
- Set a Blob storage dataset as the **sink**.

Or you can use **Azure Storage [Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer)**. You can use the copy-and-paste activity to move from a file share to a blob container.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax to copy everything in an Azure File Share to a Blob Container using [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json):

```
azcopy cp "https://foo.file.core.windows.net/[FILE SHARE]?[SAS KEY]" "https://foo.blob.core.windows.net/[BLOB CONTAINER]?[SAS KEY]" --recursive=true
```